# OCaml: Removing duplicates from a list while maintaining order from the right

Tags: ocaml

I just read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/BuUzcJtd3Ig/zqYIjVyJdjoJ) and find it interesting.

I implement the `remove from the left` function in a few minutes:

```
(*
 * remove duplicate from left:
 * 1 2 1 3 2 4 5 -> 1 2 3 4 5
 * *)
let rem_from_left lst =
  let rec is_member n mlst =
    match mlst with
    | [] -> false
    | h::tl ->
        begin
          if h=n then true
          else is_member n tl
        end
  in
  let rec loop lbuf rbuf =
    match rbuf with
    | [] -> lbuf
    | h::tl ->
        begin
          if is_member h lbuf then loop lbuf tl
          else loop (h::lbuf) rbuf
        end
  in
  List.rev (loop [] lst)
```

I know I could implement the `is_member` by `Map` or `hashtable` to make it faster, but in this moment that's not my concern.

In the case of implementing the `remove from the right`, I can  implement it by `List.rev`:

```
(*
 * remove duplicate from right:
 * 1 2 1 3 2 4 5 -> 1 3 2 4 5
 * *)
let rem_from_right lst =
  List.rev (rem_from_left (List.rev lst))
```

I'm wondering if we can implement it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accumulating the values on the way recursing to the end, you can collect the values on the way back up:

```
let rem_from_right lst =
  let rec is_member n mlst =
    match mlst with
    | [] -> false
    | h::tl ->
        begin
          if h=n then true
          else is_member n tl
        end
  in
  let rec loop lbuf =
    match lbuf with
    | [] -> []
    | h::tl ->
        begin
        let rbuf = loop tl
        in
          if is_member h rbuf then rbuf
          else h::rbuf
        end
  in
  loop lst
```

Comment: This seems like a very complicated and inefficient solution. Why not traverse the list from right to left instead of from left to right?

Comment: @AaditMShah: `fold` is definitely better, OTOH this is closer to what OP had so could be more instructive, and it shows that some minimal changes are enough to make the program work. +1 to your answer too.

Comment: Well, the `is_member` function is just the `List.mem` function and the `loop` function is kind of like the `List.fold_left` function. There's no need to reinvent the wheel unless you want to understand how the wheel works.

Comment: @AaditMShah I agree, but it seems out philosophies differ - `fold` is definitely the way to go in the real world but I'd rather leave that for the OP to discover later, while I think that it'll be great to illustrate this kind of recursion to the OP.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I would implement `remove_from_right`:

```
let uniq_cons x xs = if List.mem x xs then xs else x :: xs

let remove_from_right xs = List.fold_right uniq_cons xs []
```

Similarly, you can implement `remove_from_left` as follows:

```
let cons_uniq xs x = if List.mem x xs then xs else x :: xs

let remove_from_left xs = List.rev (List.fold_left cons_uniq [] xs)
```

Both have their advantages and disadvantages:

1. Although `List.fold_left` is tail recursive and takes constant space yet it folds the list in reverse order. Hence, you need to `List.rev` the result.
2. Although `List.fold_right` doesn't need to be followed by a `List.rev` yet it takes linear space instead of constant space to produce the result.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What is the time-complexity of this algorithm?