# Ocaml argument cannot be applied without label

Tags: ocaml, opam

I am compiling an ocaml project on my linux machine I am getting this error

```
The function applied to this argument has type 
?eq:('week4 -> 'week4 -> bool ) -> bool 
This argument cannot be applied without label.
```

Here is the code

```ml
let rec reduceandor (ee: e_expression) : e_expression = 
  match ee with
  | EE_loc_function_EEL (ll, f, eel) ->
    fail "EE_loc_function_EEL, reduceandor, transform2.ml"
  | EE_function_EEL (f, eel) when (f = Function.AND) || (f = Function.OR) ->
    (* https://stackoverflow.com/a/30634912/702977 *)
    let uniq_cons x xs = if List.mem (fun ee0 ee1 -> ee0 = ee1) x xs then xs else x :: xs in
    let remove_from_right xs = List.fold_right uniq_cons xs [] in
    let eel_wo_duplicates = remove_from_right eel in
    if List.length eel_wo_duplicates = 1
      then List.nth eel_wo_duplicates 0
      else EE_function_EEL (f, eel_wo_duplicates)
  | _ ->
    ee
```

The error is in this line

```
let uniq_cons x xs = if List.mem (fun ee0 ee1 -> ee0 = ee1) x xs then xs else x :: xs
```

The issue is when I compile the project on a mac machine everything works just fine.

The ocaml version on both machine is: `4.07.1`

Opam version : `2.0.2`

Comment: The OCaml compiler shows a code extract including the line and column number in the error message. Can you post the full extract with all details please? We can't help properly with only part of the information.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using an alternative standard library that hides the original implementation of `List.mem`. As the error indicates, you need the equality predicate to be associated with a label, like this:

```ml
List.mem ~eq:(fun ee0 ee1 -> ee0 = ee1) x xs
```

Comment: It changed nothing, I also tried `?eq:` .

Comment: Which additional library did you use?

Comment: At the very least, adding a label should have changed the error message.

Comment: Small note: `(fun ee0 ee1 -> ee0 = ee1)` is equivalent to `(=)`